# Show or Appear - which one to use?

Tags: synonyms

Which one is correct?

> Apple to *show* at bottom of dropdown
>
> Apple to *appear* at bottom of dropdown

Context: It's an announcement title trying to convey that the entry *Apple* will now be available at the bottom of a dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

We  show something to  somebody.

Something appears.

Since  Apple will now be available, the  correct  choice  seems  to  be   appear.

> **Apple to appear  at  (the )  bottom of ( the )drop down**

Since it is an advertisement  I think the use of  articles  is optional

Answer (score 0):

Appear is fine, but I would change *to* to *will*.  *To* connotes an intention, whereas *will* is imperative.

> *Apple* will appear at [the] bottom of [the] dropdown

Also, omitting singular articles is not really correct.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33304/when-can-an-article-be-omitted

As another alternative you could say

> *Apple* will be displayed at the bottom of the dropdown